# Firebase Push notification-customizing click event when app in background

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Firebase push notification generated from console by default opens launcher activity on clicking when app is in background.Is there any way to customise the click events when app is in background since onMessageReceived is not called?I looked at other answers but still not able to implement tht..

Comment: Just override `onMessageReceived()` in your service extending `FireBaseMessagingService`

Comment: @Gaurav onMessageReceived() is only called when app is in foreground

Comment: ya, right ,
check this 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive 
 Handle messages in a backgrounded app

Comment: @Gaurav already read tht..can we handle this without using custom server or curl commands?

Comment: check my answer and try

Comment: You currently cannot override the click behavior for the notification when the app is backgrounded. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809885/firebase-push-notifications-update-db/37814092#37814092 (and those linked from there).