# Firebase notification doesn't work properly if application is in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have an FirebaseMessagingService class for Firebase:

```
public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();

    Bitmap remote_picture = null;
    remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

    intent = new Intent(this, HomeDrawer.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Title");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif);
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(remote_picture);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification noti = new Notification();
    noti = notificationBuilder.build();
    //notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000});
    //notificationBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    notificationManager.notify(0,noti);

    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
}
```

If the application is in background, (not actively open, but in the background, not closed) the notification smallIcon and LargeIcon doesn't appear, the default ones for android appears instead, also if I changed

```
 intent = new Intent(this, HomeDrawer.class);
```

to any other activity class, it doesn't open the class I specified and opens the last class I left open in the background.

What am I doing wrong? SmallIcon and LargeIcon are not working properly if the background. However, notification message appears fine and also remoteMessage.getData(); gets the data correctly, it's all about the behavior of icons and intent class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809885/firebase-push-notifications-update-db/37843845#37843845

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44800598/7329597 it is available.You can find solution and hope you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because notifications are handled differently if your app is in background.

If app is running in foreground then yours  `FcmMessagingService` will be executed and you are handling notifications on your own.

If app is not running, notifications are handled by the android system itseld.`FcmMessagingService` is never executed. For this case you have to properly setup icon on the server!

I believe this behaviour happens since introduction of `doze` mechanism.

The notification sent from server should look something like this

```
"notification" : {
  "body" : "great match!",
  "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "icon" : "myicon", // the name of the resource
  "sound" : "mySound"
}
```

Comment: Understandable, how can I setup icon on the server? Also for the intent class issue, how can I manage this?

Comment: @MahmoudTarek those clases supposed to be activities and should be registered in Manifest file.

Comment: Updated answer to have notification template

Please accept answer.

Comment: Thank you, the "icon" attribute works but for small icon only, how can I get large icon to work too from the object itself?

Comment: It seems there is no support for large icon ATM. Look here for more info https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/84

Please accept answer

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.