# Firebase ChildEventListener OnChildAdded doesnt read the last child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code that should make a notification every time a new child is added, however there are conditions that should be met in order for the notification to occur but what I do not understand is that it doesnt read the newly added child unless I start the activity all over again, is there any edit that I can do so it can read that newly added child?

```
root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String id = dataSnapshot.child("FA_ID").getValue().toString();
        String Bystander_id = dataSnapshot.child("Bystander_ID").getValue().toString();
        String location = dataSnapshot.child("Location").getValue().toString();
        String is_done  = dataSnapshot.child("Done").getValue().toString();


        if(uid.compareTo(id)==0 && is_done.compareTo("false")==0){
        Toast.makeText(HomeScreenFirstAid.this,is_done, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(HomeScreenFirstAid.this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        String header = "REPORT RECEIVED:";
        builder.setContentTitle(header);
        String body = "Location:"+location;
        builder.setContentText(body);

        Intent intent = new Intent("ph.edu.upm.agila.extendthelife.controller.rescuer.MainScreenRescuer");
        intent.putExtra("Bystander_id",Bystander_id);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(HomeScreenFirstAid.this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainScreenRescuer.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NM.notify(0,builder.build());
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `

```
NM.notify(0,builder.build());
```

to `

```
NM.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(),builder.build());
```

Anyway, if you want to send an notification when new data arrive, you shouldn't use Service or Activity, you should use FCM,
Read here: [Firebase push notifications update DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809885/firebase-push-notifications-update-db?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: can you please explain your solution