# Unable to send data message using firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm using firebase console and can send only Notification messages using it.

Is there a way to send data messages using the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now send *[notification message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications)* via the console. Note that it is different from *data messages*; notification messages only trigger the `onMessageReceived` callback when the app is in the foreground.

They are inside the *advanced options* tab on the *compose message* screen.

[image]

Just expand it and type your key/value map.

[image]

These will be included into the data field of the notification.

Comment: This doesn't work properly. If your app is in the background you won't receive a callback to 'onMessageReceived' even though you are supposed to if you include 'data'.

Comment: @WiseShepherd I actually noticed the same problem yesterday, it can only send _notification message_ and not _data message_. I updated my answer.

Comment: This works only when app is in foreground. When app is in background, it considers only Notification data from payload and ignores data part. This leads to no control to the app as notification type messages will be handled by system alone.

Only option is to use an external server of your own or send from a rest client.

Answer (score 29):

The Firebase Notifications Console can only be used to send notification messages. It cannot be used to send data messages.

See the table in [message types in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

> **Notification message**
>
> *Use scenario*: FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys.
>
> *How to send*:
>
> 1. Use your app server and FCM server API: Set the notification key. May have optional data payload. Always collapsible.
> 2. Use the Notifications console: Enter the Message Text, Title, etc., and send. Add optional data payload by providing Custom data in the Notifications console. Always collapsible.
>
> **Data message**
>
> *Use scenario*: Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.
>
> *How to send*:
>
> - Use your app server and FCM server API: Set the data key only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible.

Comment: Wrong answer.. You can use it to update DB if he will use Messaging API ("downstream msg")

Comment: You can definitely send downstream data messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging by sending a POST request to the HTTP endpoint. But you cannot send data messages from the [Firebase Notifications Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification), which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 29):

You can test both notification message and data message using Postman(rest client for testing http request).See screen shots:

[image]

In header pass:

```
key:Content-Type, value:application/json
key:Authorization:key=<Server key>
```

Comment: This way is no available more. Now you need also OAuth2 token

Comment: for the correct server key, click the settings icon in the top left of the firebase console, then Project settings > Cloud Messaging > Server Key

Comment: Just confirmed using postman to send data message is still available.

Answer (score 22):

Please look here: [Firebase push notifications update DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809885/firebase-push-notifications-update-db?noredirect=1&lq=1), my post from June.

In conclusion, you need send HTTP POST request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
"score": "5x1",
"time": "15:10"
},
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't fit in the context of this question. Please check the question asked - *he specifically asks about sending data message using console which is not possible*.

Comment: if you want to send a data message to a specific topic, the value of the property "to" must be in the form of "/topics/TOPIC_ID" , otherwise you will get an error

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: "Upvote" because of providing an alternative! Please add a note saying "It's not possible to send data messages from FB Console atm and providing an alternative instead" in your answer to complete it.