# how to show the notification data in new activity using firebase in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Here is my code of notification. Actually, I'm getting the notification perfectly but when I click on the notification in a phone the app will open directly (when the app is in the background or killed). When the app is in the foreground, the `ResultActivity` will open correctly when I click on notification but the data is not showing over there.

Please check my code and let me know what I did wrong.

**FirebaseMessagingService.java:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

Map<String, String> data;
String Title, Message, PushType;
String body, title;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom() + "");
    data = remoteMessage.getData();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

    try {
        Log.e("data", jsonObject.toString());
        body = jsonObject.getString("body");
        title = jsonObject.getString("title");
        Log.e("body", body);
        Log.e("title", title);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("exception>>>", e.toString() + "");
        e.printStackTrace();
        body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Log.e("body>>>", body + "");
    }

    sendNotification(body, title);
}



private void sendNotification(String message, String title){

    Log.e("message>>>", message + "");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("body",message);
    intent.putExtra("title",title);

    int requestCode = 0;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fc)
            //.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification

}
```

**ResultActivity.java:**

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView Title,Message ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_view);
        Title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        Message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);

        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {
            for(String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet())
            {
                if(key.equals("title"))
                    Title.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));
      else if(key.equals("message"))
                Message.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));

            }

        }

    }
}
```

**activity_notification_view.xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:hint="title"
    android:gravity="center" />


<TextView
    android:hint="message"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("body",message);
intent.putExtra("title",title);
```

//in activity add

```
String  body =getIntent().getStringExtra("body");
String  title =getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

Comment: ohh yaa it works, if my app is in foreground, but when my app is in background or killed the issue remain same that when i click on notification directly the app will open instead of result activity .

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 0):

You are using different key in  putExtra and in getExtra.

In above code you are passing data in **body and title** key and you are trying to find the data on **title and message**.

Use same key for for getter and setter.

Comment: yup thanks a lot ,but it works when app is in foreground, if app is in background or killed the issue remain same that when i click on notification directly app will open instead of result activity ...?

Comment: with type of FCM message type you are sending? Data message or Notification message ?

Comment: i think i m using notification message after my Research, can you tell me how to send data message using firebase.??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726030/unable-to-send-data-message-using-firebase-console

Comment: you have to add data as key value pair, check the above link.