# Firebase Cloud Messaging Data Messages with Console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I would like to know if it is possible to send Data Messages only (not Notification Messages) with the FCM console.

In case it is not, how can I do it in Php for all users in a specific time (depending from the local time of the user) in the future and not now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726030/unable-to-send-data-message-using-firebase-console

Comment: Thank you, I already saw it, but I wasn't sure, whether they have changed something.